# Python decorator logger

Tags: python, decorator

I have the following code:

```
def log(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        func_str = func.__name__
        args_str = ', '.join(args)
        kwargs_str = ', '.join([':'.join([str(j) for j in i]) for i in kwargs.iteritems()])
        with open('log.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(func_str)
            f.write(args_str)
            f.write(kwargs_str)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper()


@log
def example(a, b):
    print('example')
```

However, even without calling any function, I still get the error:

```
TypeError: example() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)
```

Can someone explain to me why this happens, because it seems the function is called, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should return the `wrapper` function without calling it:

```
return wrapper
```

Calling it implies the call to `wrapper` has to be evaluated, which you're however calling with the wrong signature.

Answer (score 5):

Because you are calling it here:

```
return wrapper()
```

It should be:

```
return wrapper
```

Comment: That did it! Makes sense indeed now I see it compared to examples.